# sharing data between a service and its activity

Tags: android, multithreading, android-service

It seems that the usual way of exchanging data between a service and the activity is through handlers or message. If, however, I'm in an activity and start a service I implemented in the same process, why can't I just access their shared data, since they run in the same address space? Does it affect that there are basically two classes (activity and service)? If not, how can one access the other's data fields?

And if they even run in the same thread (UI), the sync is not a problem anymore, I just wonder if there's a easier way to share data between them in this case. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a simpler way in this case.
When the binding is established, you can cast the IBinder to your Service's type.

Here is the relevent code snippet from 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html

```
private LocalService mBoundService;

private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
        // This is called when the connection with the service has been
        // established, giving us the service object we can use to
        // interact with the service.  Because we have bound to a explicit
        // service that we know is running in our own process, we can
        // cast its IBinder to a concrete class and directly access it.
        mBoundService = ((LocalService.LocalBinder)service).getService();

        // Tell the user about this for our demo.
        Toast.makeText(Binding.this, R.string.local_service_connected,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Comment: so how to access (pass) variables between them?

Comment: How do you mean? You can call the service's methods.

Comment: yes, but I mean once the value in the service is changed, I should be able to get it. something like monitoring the service

Comment: Well, there is nothing about this in your question, so you should update it accordingly, or create a new question for it. However, it is trivial that you can register a callback method to the service after the binding. And that callback could be called by the service whenever the value is changed.

Answer (score 0):

I think sending intents should work.

Intent in = new Intent(youractivity.this,YourService.class);
//here you can put val in intent using 
//putExtra methods
startService(in);

After this, in the service you can recieve the value that you sent from the activity.
I think this is similar as we do between activities :)
Hope it works.

Comment: then how to pass value from the service to the activity?